# Site isn't working well in mobile, what are some quick fixes?

Tags: html, css

I'm making some small changes for a client to checkmaid.com, but I realized it's not working well in iPhones specifically. I've noticed that other websites will scale down to fit (without being actual responsive sites), but this one doesn't. I've tried using the following, but no luck:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

The backgrounds are also not spanning the entire width of the top level divs and I've been unable to fix that trying different CSS out.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = yes">
```

Comment: I added this and that did indeed help, but now about 15% of the right side of the page is blank (using an iPhone, to reiterate). Any idea on this? Thanks so much.

Comment: this might be related to your images in your document, keep in mind that max(by max I mean recommended) width size for iphone is 980px, make sure you don't have any images or even margins and padding adding this white space